# Lambda inconstant when querying my RDS database

Tags: javascript, aws-lambda, async-await, amazon-rds

When I go to test my code, the lambda does nothing, and at other times it runs my query and returns the data I have queried for. It's very inconsistent.  It doesn't even give me an error. I am also  using a proxy and that's not showing any errors. That's also not triggering.

I suspect it's something to do with the await/ async...

Here is my code:

```
async function RDSToken() {

   
  vr signer =  new AWS.RDS.Signer({
    region: 'us-east-1', 
    hostname: 'proxy',
    port: 3306,
    username: 'username' 
  });

var host ='proxy'
var user ='username'
var db ='name'

let token =  signer.getAuthToken({username: 'admin' });
let connectionConfig = {
    host: host, 
    user: user,
    database: db, 
    ssl: { rejectUnauthorized: false},
    password: token,
    authSwitchHandler: function ({pluginName, pluginData}, cb) {
        console.log("Setting new auth handler.");
    }
  };
connectionConfig.authSwitchHandler = (data, cb) => {
  if (data.pluginName === 'mysql_clear_password') {
      let password = token + '\0';
      let buffer = Buffer.from(password);
      cb(null, password);
  }};


  try {
      connection =  await mysql2.createConnection(connectionConfig);
  } catch(err) {
      console.error('error connecting to the database');
      console.error(err);
      var response = {  
          statusCode: 500,
          "headers": {
              "Content-Type": "application/json"
          },
          body: 'error connecting to the database' +err
      };
      return response;
  }

return connection

}
async function randomfact() {
  
  var connection = await RDSToken();
  
  let sql = 'SELECT * FROM quote_header;';
  return await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     connection.query(sql, (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      }
      else {
        resolve(result);
      }
    });
  });
}
async function Dashboard() {
    
  const result = await randomfact();
  console.log(result)

}
```

Comment: "When I go to test my code, the lambda does nothing, and at other times it runs my query and returns the data I have queried for. It's very inconsistent. "  This could be caused by inability to reach the RDS instance from some of the subnets in which the lambda runs.

Comment: you need to describe "does nothing" in more detail. Is it returning an empty response, or an error message, or is Lambda saying the function timed out? Those are really the only three incorrect behaviors that could happen in this Lambda function, so which one is it? What does the CloudWatch Log stream look like for one of your "does nothing" invocations?

Comment: I get nothing, no error, and nothing gets returned, and the lambda is not timing out. It invoked the lambda and cloud watch sees that it's been invoked but shows no error, nothing gets returned ect.

Comment: I have checked and the Lambda is running on the same subnet as the database and the proxy.

Answer (score 0):

So I was correct there is something to do await/asnyc/promise.
Here is my updated code.

```
    const connection =  mysql2.createPool({
    host: "host",
    user: "admin",
    password: "pw",
    database : 'name',
    waitForConnections: true,
    connectionLimit: 3,

  }) 
  
 SelectAllElements = (connection) =>{
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
        connection.query('SELECT * FROM quote_header ',  (error, elements)=>{
            if(error){
                return reject(error);
            }
            return resolve(elements);
        });
    });
};

async function Dashboard() {



  try{
  const result1 = await SelectAllElements(connection);
  console.log(result1)
// here you can do something with the three results
} catch(error){
console.log(error)
}
}
```

But this works around 95% of the time. It doesn't like to work the first time I run the lambda but after then it works for a short time, then returns null again, then works again. I still dont understand what's causing it not to connect.

Comment: Another thing is, that it will not work but the next time I run the lambda it returns the null lambda run with the right data and the current lambda run with the right data...